# I cannot print the items from element.all statement in protractor

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

I'm using element.all and I want to be able to actually use `console.log` to print out an items text as well as the count.  But for some reason I can't.  `expect()` works fine, but why can I not convert the count for example into something I can use?

ie:

```
this.dropdownText = function(locator) { 
    return $$(locator).then ( function(elems) {
        console.log( elems.count() ); //does not print whats expected....
        console.log( elems[0] ); //does not print out the first element
});
```

I am wondering because I want to use the dropdown COUNT in a loop going forwards.  Why can I not print these things?  Is there a way?

Comment: Your braces aren't matched, there's no `}` for the inner `function`.

Comment: This is just an example, not exact code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this one:

```
  this.dropdownText = function(locator) { 
        $$(locator).then(function(elems) {
            console.log(elems.count()); 
            elems[0].getText().then(function(elem){
                console.log(elem);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: That seems to work, it appears I have to use .then within the element to be able to print it out.  Thank you my friend.

Comment: How come i can't assign elems.count() or the element to a variable though so i can use outside of the .then clause?

Comment: you can, but almost everything is assync in the protractor and based on promises, so if you create variable and after that assign value to it in 'then' block and try to access it after then block immediately - it wont be success. In this case promise wont be resolved yet, but control flow will go futher

Comment: what do you mean by 'promise'?